# Observable gets doubled

Tags: authentication, typescript, rxjs

im fairly new to Rxjs, but now I have problem:
I have this code:

```
const requestStream = Observable.of({
    url: siteLocation + 'login',
    body: {
        personnelNumber : personnelNumber,
        password : password
    }
});

requestStream.subscribe(response => {
    console.log("Hello")
});

const responseStream : Observable<Response> = requestStream
.flatMap(request => {
    console.log("Hello2");

    return this.http.post(request.url, JSON.stringify(request.body), {
        headers: this.getHeaders()
    });
});

const jsonStream = responseStream.map(response => response.json());

jsonStream.subscribe(json => {
    console.log("Hello3");
    this.authToken = json.authToken;
});
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
Hello
Hello2
Hello2
Hello3
```

Why does the flatMap doubles my request Stream and even if this is indented, why is the resulting json stream normal again?

The problem is, I'm loggin into my API with this snippet, and I log in twice, thus the second time I log in, my first authToken is invalidated and I get a new one. But because I only save the first one, my saved token is never valid.

I checked the Requests and Responses in Chrome, they are all correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The problem was that I subscribed to the json stream. When I used map (because I wanted to reuse the stream) everything worked.
I think this is a bug, I will report it.